# can not change layout_gravity from left

Tags: android, layout

I have a simple LinerLayout with 3 child linear layouts , each have a text view
when Im trying to align the text view to the center or to the right , nothing happens. its always aligned to the left, why ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/alert_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="TYPE"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/alert_type"
        android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="ALERT"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/alert_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/alert_details"
            android:text="DETAILS" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide `orientation` to each `LinearLayout` and set `gravity` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use RelativeLayout instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/alert_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TYPE"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/alert_type"
    android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="ALERT"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/alert_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alert_details"
        android:text="DETAILS" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

or you can use gravity to the linearlayout not textview..like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/alert_type"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TYPE"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `gravity` like

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` of `TextView` to `match_parent`

Comment: Glad it helped, well i didnt downvoted but it is downvoted probably as a `low question`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
android:gravity="center"
```

for each `TextView's` and `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

change layout_width="wrap_content" and layout_gravity="centre"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alert_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="TYPE" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/alert_type"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ALERT" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/alert_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DETAILS" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below XML code for your layout, in which I set all textview at center position

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alert_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TYPE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/alert_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="ALERT" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DETAILS" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You just need to add android:gravity="center" in your linear layout. You can also provide any alignment like right, center_vertical etc.